# Verificar caracter por posição em C#

Tags: javascript, c#

Boa noite, desenvolvendo um programinha em C# pela primeira vez, eu ja fiz este programa em JS e agora estou aprendendo C# e passando o programa para ele. preciso verificar caractere por caractere de uma variavel, em JS precisei somente colocar a variavel e a posição do caractere que queria ver (variavel[0] //primeiro caractere da variavel). é possivel fazer esta verificação em C#? tenho uma variavel com um numero binario dentro, preciso verificar em que posições aparecem o digito 1.

```
for (var i = 0; i < nums_mapa_bits.length; i++) {

        nums_mapa_bits[i] == 1 ? bits_ativos.push(i + 1) : '';

    }
```

a variavel 'nums_mapa_bits' esta com o binario dentro, quero reproduzir este for em C#, por enquanto ainda não achei um jeito de fazer isto.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    string nums_mapa_bits = "0101000111";
    List<int> bits_ativos = new List<int>();

    for(var i=0; i< nums_mapa_bits.Length; i++)
    {
       if(nums_mapa_bits[i] == '1')
       {
          Console.WriteLine($"Posicao {i} é ativo");
          bits_ativos.Add(i);
    
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Em C# você consegue sim acessar o elemento de uma string pelo índice. Tente usar esse código acima e adapte para o seu caso. Eu considerei que esse número binário que você tem é uma string.